# How to set TextInputLayout's outlined box floating hint background color

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

How to change the background color of the floating hint in a text input layout outline box style to transparent. I think the attached picture clearly states the issue It should be red above the stroke and white below). What I did to change the background itself was:

```
<style name="App.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image: Outlined box with corrupted background]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the style docs in https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/ you can see the "Filled text view" supports the `boxBackgroundColor` attribute while the "Outlined text field" does not.

So I don't think there's a proper solution to this problem unless you find the inner hint `TextView` within the layout and change the background manually. But that would be quite hacky since it depends on the implementation of the `TextInputLayout` staying the same.

Comment: I kindof refuse to accept this as the final solution. Of course i saw that the documentation is missing that feature. But i do not like how the filled boxes look like. Hmm, maybe i will play around with their stlyle

Comment: You shouldn't accept it as the solution. I was just commenting to help out. Actually, it should have been a comment on your question, not an answer

Comment: Sorry, my comment sounded way to offending when i reread it now. It was more a talking to myself kindof refuse to accept. I appreciate your answer though:)

Comment: @DennisH. Did you find any solution? I am kinda stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @dtb305 No, I have not. I seems that you would have to restyle the whole widget. Currently it also lays on top of the edit text which makes the border disappear. With a transparent background it would not. Also what to do where the background colour touches the inside color. I see why android does not support that. It is complex to realise and may not even look good. But I appreciate an answer if anyone is going to try this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but I managed to have a uniform background inside the box strokes for the [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout) in [outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#box_background_outline) box mode.

[image]

In my example, the box corners have a 10dp radius (`text_input_layout_box_radius`). Also, the [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText) has height of 80dp (`text_input_edit_text_height`).

I defined a style for the TextInputLayout in which I apply a custom background shape:

```xml
    <style name="MyTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_input_background</item>
        <!-- ... other customizations ... -->
    </style>
```

The `text_input_background.xml` drawable is defined as a layer-list:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="@dimen/text_input_edit_text_height"
        android:top="@dimen/text_input_background_padding_top">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/text_input_layout_box_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/<your_background_color>" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The `text_input_background_padding_top` is equal to 13dp and it does the magic here. In my case, it centers the shape inside the box. It is needed to compensate for the hint height which is 30sp in my case, it can be modified with the `hintTextAppearance` attribute. You will probably have to find the correct padding value corresponding to your hint text height.

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Setting a separate background color just for the hint feels a bit weird and doesn't look like something that's officially supported, but the setHint() method takes a CharSequence parameter - maybe you could try a SpannabeString with BackgroundColorSpan.

I tried and it works for me :)